# How can i make turbolinks work properly on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I started a new Rails 4 project in which I want all the capabilities of turbolinks, I know rails 4 comes with it activated, but in my case it seems not.

It is on the gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks
```

and on application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
```

In the layout (app/views/layouts/application.html.haml) I have this on the header

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
= csrf_meta_tags
```

and this at the bottom:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

**What else do I need to get it working?**

Every time i click on a link, it loads CSS file and all JS, and the page is fully rendered.

Am I missing something ???

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you read the [documentation for Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: I'm using firefox, i already checked history.pushState is suported

Comment: @adbeel Have you tried creating a brand-new app and testing it?

Comment: It is a brand new app, the only thing i added is bootstrap, haml and one model. I'll try without these tools, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks like it's implemented correctly to me?